# Rspec NameError, how can I refactor this code and use routing helpers correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
#spec/features/senseis_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Senseis" do
  subject { page }
  @paths = [senseis_path, new_sensei_path, edit_sensei_path(1), sensei_path(1)]

  describe "sensei can not access" do
    before { login_as_sensei }

    @paths.each do |path|
      describe "#{path}" do
        before { visit path }
        it { should have_selector(error, text: "You are not authorized") }
      end
    end
  end

end
```

But it's giving me an error `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'senseis_path'`

I've tried adding `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` to the spec helper but it didn't help.

The long way works:

```
describe "sensei can not access" do
  before { login_as_sensei }

  describe "senseis#index" do
    before { visit senseis_path }
    it { should have_selector(error, text: "You are not authorized") }
  end
end
```

Ideally I'd like to define this in another file and then just call `deny_access_to(path_one, path_two, ...)`

P.S. `error` is defined elsewhere.

Routes:

```
                  root        /                             dashboard#index
               senseis GET    /senseis(.:format)            senseis#index
                       POST   /senseis(.:format)            senseis#create
            new_sensei GET    /senseis/new(.:format)        senseis#new
           edit_sensei GET    /senseis/:id/edit(.:format)   senseis#edit
                sensei GET    /senseis/:id(.:format)        senseis#show
                       PUT    /senseis/:id(.:format)        senseis#update
                       DELETE /senseis/:id(.:format)        senseis#destroy
    new_sensei_session GET    /user/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        sensei_session POST   /user/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_sensei_session DELETE /user/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       sensei_password POST   /user/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_sensei_password GET    /user/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_sensei_password GET    /user/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                       PUT    /user/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
```

Comment: Please run `rake routes` and show us the output.

Comment: Hi Charles, I've added the routes.

Comment: Try changing your first description at the top to `describe SenseisController do` without quotation marks, that should make the routes available

Comment: I changed it now but same error is generated.

Comment: Well, what does it say?

Comment: The exact same `NameError`, and I restarted `spork` every time just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Senseis" do

  def should_deny_access_to(paths)
    paths.each do |path|
      login_as_sensei
      visit path
      page.should have_selector(error, text: "You are not authorized")
    end
  end

  it { should_deny_access_to [senseis_path, new_sensei_path, edit_sensei_path(1), sensei_path(1)] }

end
```

Or use shared example groups.